# Displaying ImageView in a definite place on layout

Tags: android

developers. Is anybody know, what functions can I use to display an ImageView in a correct place on it`s parent Layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use AbsoluteLayout - which is deprecated and using hardcoded coordinates is bad practice in general.

You better use some relations to other objects like 'align', 'gravity', 'weigth', etc.

Comment: Does only AbsoluteLayout allow to operate with coordinates?

Comment: In other layouts you can set 'padding' and 'margins', and then set android:layout_gravity="left|top"

Comment: I use Relative layout, which consists of 2 imageviews, but there isn`t such property like layout_gravity

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#attr_android:gravity

Comment: Is it not the same as layout_gravity, Are there differences between this properties? By the way, there is also no such property like gravity in RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RelativeLayout as mentioned by others. If you want to place it in a specific location relative to its parent then the RelativeLayout does provide some degree of control such as android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" or android:layout_below="@+id/myFirstImageView", etc. These layout positions which are relative to the parent and/or relative to another view, are available as settings in xml or in code.